# No color in render preview

Tags: color

[image: did not touch anything except adding material then changing base color]

[image: render preview]

Hi guys! A newbie here. I don't know what's causing this (I was doing a lighthouse project before this). Then when I wanted to add a base color, this happened. I loaded my old project which was tables and chairs(it was finished with wood textures and stuff), same thing happened. Tried with a new default cube and still the same result. Answers are greatly appreciated!
PS. Sorry for my bad grammar.

Comment: the latest AMD driver doesn't work, try to switch to the previous one, or try Properties panel > Render > Performance > High Quality Normals

Comment: thank you so much it works! it seems the problem was the latest amd driver. thank you again @moonboots. your help is much appreciated!